# How to fix the error "QObject::moveToThread:" in opencv in python?

Tags: python, qt, opencv

I am using opencv2 in python with the code

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("output", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)       
cv2.imshow("output",im)
cv2.resizeWindow('output', 400,400)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have the error as

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1d2c9cf0) is not the object's thread (0x1d347b20).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1d2c9cf0)
```

I debug and found that it happened when I use `cv2.waitKey(0)`. How should I fix it? Thanks

Update: I am using 3.3.0.0. If I use older version, I have error

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvDestroyAllWindows, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 577
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/demo_handbone.py", line 220, in <module>
    demo(net, im_name)
  File "tools/demo_handbone.py", line 159, in demo
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:577: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvDestroyAllWindows
```

Comment: My guess is something odd happened regarding either Qt or the most recent version of opencv2 might have a bug. Did you just upgrade a package recently?

Comment: Right. I have reinstall opencv2 and I got the problem.

Comment: Try installing an older version. Did you use pip to install?

Comment: Yes. I use pip. How can I install an older version of opencv in python? Thanks

Comment: `pip install opencv-python==` will list the available versions. Then you do `pip install opencv-python==3.1.0.0`, for example.

Comment: Thanks. I am using version 3.3.0.0. I tried to use older version but I got the error as my update question

Comment: 1. Run `sudo pip uninstall opencv-python`. 2. Which distro of Linux are you running? If it's Ubuntu/Debian, 
`sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`.

Comment: It worked now. Thanks so much. I will delete the question. Is it ok?

Comment: Nice. I'll put it in answer format. (My friend was having the same error.)

Comment: If you have KDE installed, there is a conflict between system Qt and the wheel-bundled version. `sudo apt remove libqt5x11extras5` fixed the problem for me _BUT_  will basically kill KDE, so beware if you use that as your main gui. See: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/46

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, uninstall any versions of OpenCV you may have installed. If you installed using `pip`:

```
sudo pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Next, try installing OpenCV using your Linux distro's package manager. For Ubuntu/Debian, this is:

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv
```

Comment: I am using `virtualenv` and my problem persists after 
1. `$ pip uninstall opencv-python`. 2. `$ sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv` 3. `$ pip install opencv-python`

Comment: `opencv-python` in pip ships with a opencv 3 library, but `python-opencv` binding in `apt` uses the `libopencv-dev` library which is opencv2. So I believe your method doesn't solve the problem for those (and me) who need to use opencv3 in python.

Comment: Doesn't work (same error persists). opencv-python-3.3.0.10 in python vs. libopencv2.4 in OS

Comment: @TusharGoswami Facing the same, any update on the problem?

Comment: This "solution" basically disables the use of virtual environments.

Comment: doesn't work for me https://pastebin.com/raw/BvsuyT6Z  libopencv-highgui2.4v5 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: this solution is outdated for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Thank you this solved my "Aborted (core dumped)" error that happens opening labelme

Comment: This worked for me: `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv` I do think it disables virtual environments though

Answer (score 32):

I got same problem, it was from `opencv-python` version problem for me.
My Linux machine's environment is as following:

```sh
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
...
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
$ date
Tue Aug 11 11:43:16 KST 2020
$ python --version
Python 3.7.8
$ pip list|grep Qt
PyQt5                5.15.0
PyQt5-sip            12.8.0
$ pip list|grep opencv-python
opencv-python        4.3.0.38
```

I downgraded opencv-python **4.3.0.38** to **4.3.0.36**.

```sh
$ pip uninstall opencv-python
$ pip install opencv-python==4.3.0.36
$ pip list|grep opencv-python
opencv-python        4.3.0.36
```

Comment: This is the only answer in this thread that worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: This lead to the following error for me:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed

Comment: Downgrading worked also for me. Did a more strong downgrade from `4.5.3.56` to `4.1.2.30`

Answer (score 14):

This can happen if you are using an Anaconda virtual environment and did both `conda install pyqt`<sup>(1)</sup> *and* `pip install opencv-python`. This creates a conflict between the two PyQt versions (`opencv-python` ships with its own) and causes the errors.

The solution is to install PyQt via `pip`, i.e. `pip install PyQt5`.

---

<sub>(1) Or anything that depends on `pyqt`, e.g. `conda install matplotlib`.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix this problem by installing new pyqt.

if you are using anaconda, just write down below:

$ conda install pyqt

Comment: This worked for me while using python 3.7. This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: What would be the analogous package for pip? There is package with the name *pyqt* in pip.

Comment: This also worked for me :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue and I posted my solution [in related issue on OpenCV github page](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/46#issuecomment-518642701). But for your convenience, I will post it here also.

In my case, I did almost all the solutions:

- installing using pip3 install opencv-python
- installing using apt install python-opencv
- I followed [@areche solution](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/46#issuecomment-495694090), I end up with `kdelibs5-plugins` which was an important module for most of my desktop environments, so I give up on uninstalling it.

Finally, I found a solution for my case

- `pip uninstall opencv-python` on all instances of my python and virtual environments
- `pip3 uninstall opencv-python` on all instances of my python and virtual environments
- `sudo apt remove python-opencv`

then I downloaded the most recent opencv, in my case `opencv-4.1.1` , I build it.
for building :

`mkdir build; cd build; ccmake ..`
then I pressed pressed `c`, again pressed `c`, then pressed `g` to generate make files, then
`sudo make -j8`
after successful building, I copied `build\lib\python3\cv2.cpython.xxxxxx.so` to `usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/` and renamed it to `cv2.so`
Do the same for each virtualenv that you have. ( I'm not sure if it is logical, but it worked for me).

then everything worked fine without any error.

Comment: The problem seems to be related with KDE. After doing the [areche_solution](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/46#issuecomment-495694090) everything worked just fine

Answer (score 4):

refer to: https://blog.csdn.net/flyfor2013/article/details/110132458

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python

pip3 install opencv-python==4.1.1.26
```

when I downgrade opencv-python 4.5 -> 4.1.1.26 then Ok

```
pip3 >= 20.3 use: pip3 install --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver opencv-python==

pip3 >= 9.0 use: pip3 install opencv-python==
```

and I try

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python

pip3 install opencv-python==4.3.0.36
```

Ok, too

Comment: It seems to work for me, with version `opencv-python` version `4.2.0.34` or less (python version `3.8.5` and ubuntu `20.04`.

Answer (score 4):

Just reinstall opencv-python lib, it's OK.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python==4.2.0.34
```

The version 4.2 is the latest opencv python that don't throw this error. I tried 4.3 or 4.4 +, it's don't work.

The main reason of this question may be the conflict between PyQt5 and OpenCV.

Comment: I have exaclty this version, "opencv-python==4.2.0.34", and I'm getting tons of this error :(

Answer (score 3):

The openCv author says that this problem comes from different Qt versions in openCv and the linux distro. That is: openCv comes with Qt4, but Qt5 is already installed.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is due to the conflict between opencv-python's own Qt5 and the one used by other packages. In my case, `matplotlib` is installed via `conda`, then `pyqt` is also installed as a `matplotlib`'s dependency. My solution is as follows:

1. Uninstall `matplotlib`: `conda remove matplotlib`
2. Install `opencv-python` and `matplotlib`: `pip install matplotlib opencv-python`

Now, `matplotlib` installed via `pip` doesn't require `pyqt` and the conflict is solved.

Note: The latest version 4.5.4.x gets error with `python 3.9`, consider using lower version such as 4.5.1.x in this case.

Comment: this helped me. Thanks a lot for sharing. I was using ubuntu 20. The conflict was caused by matplotlib and opencv-contrib-pyhon

Comment: This is the real problem. This solved the issue for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with OpenCV version, The following version solved all issues for me.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30
```

I am using - Python 3.8.5 with conda

I tried with upgrading pyqt too but it didn't work

Comment: just want to confirm for others to know: downgrading to opencv-python=4.1.2.30 solved it for me: I had opencv-contrib-python 4.5.5.62, opencv-python 4.6.0.66, opencv-python-headless 4.6.0.66 installed, along with Ubuntu 20.04.6, pycharm community edition 2023.2.3, and python 3.6.12 when this error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above mentioned method and could get opencv module working for my project which uses python3.x interpreter.

After performing few experiments, i got it working by doing the below steps:

1) Install opencv-python in your machine using:

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```

2) On the python3.x terminal find the version:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.4.1'
```

3) Get the same version of OpenCV from their [official page](https://opencv.org/releases.html).

4) Perform the CMake settings as mentioned in [opencv tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html). 
   Note the location specified in **PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH**

5) Once build has been performed, got to the install location specified in **PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH**. Move the library named **cv2.cpython-*-gnu.so** to the current python3.x dist-packages path:

```
usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2
```

6) Reload your python3 project and try again!

Answer (score 0):

This problem not present if runing opencv without virtualenviroment. 
My system:
Kbuntu 18.04 LTS
GTX 1050
CUDA 9.2
Tensorflow 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i tried to run a [detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) demo. My OS is Centos7 and i 
 uninstall some applications about qt.

find applications about qt.

```
yum list installed |grep qt
```

remove  applications

```
yum -y remove xxx...
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in higher versions of openCv like 4.3.0.38 or higher, i tried 4.3.0.36 version with pip and this problem solved for me, but in lower  version i were facing lots of problems, like window not loading correctly,If are using Ubuntu i would recommend you to uninstall opencv from your system completely and try to reinstall with command given below,

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python3
```

Comment: pip install opencv-contrib-python3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python3
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python3

Answer (score 0):

It is the compatibility issue. Even the way of "conda install install pyqt" does work. Please make sure that you can install the opencv libraries with the specific versions. Higher versions may incur the same issues.

```
pip install opencv-python==4.1.1.26
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.1.26
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did not find any solution. By trial and error, I found that my `OpenCV` version is corrupted. As a result, I deleted it and install a new fresh one. You can use one of these two options:
**1. Terminal**
run `brew uninstall opencv3` to uninstall `opencv`
then install it using `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv` command.

**2. Anaconda**
Actually, I used this method for my own problem.

1. open anaconda
2. go to the environment section and select your environment as follow:
   [image]
   then click on installed and search for `opencv`:
   [image]
   select `opencv` package and uninstall it. then try to re-install `opencv` by selecting not installed and searching for `opencv`. be careful to install the correct version.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In my application I wanted to use PyQt without any of opencv's GUI functionality, so the solution was to remove my current vertion of opencv-python, then instead `pip install opencv-python-headless` (or `opencv-contrib-python-headless` if you prefer). That way, opencv would be installed without its conflicting Qt library.

See: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python#installation-and-usage

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the python version from 3.9.13 to 3.8.10

```
conda install python=3.8.10

pip install opencv-python==4.5.2.54
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My system environment: Ubuntu 20.04  Anaconda 3.8

I was used matplotlib to display images and face this problem.
`pip install opencv-python-headless` not work for me.

`pip uninstall pyqt5` then `pip install pyqt5==5.12` and it works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same error but from a different module but the problem remains the same my opencv is not compatible with the module I am using after searching every where found this solution.

> pip install opencv-python-headless

Might not work but you can easily revert the change but removing the pip

> pip uninstall opencv-python-headless

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and I have resolved it. The reason was that I had installed opencv-python version 4.8 using pip while also installing opencv version 4.5 using conda.

```
pip install opencv-python
conda install opencv==4.5 -c conda-forge
```

This may have caused a conflict, but I resolved the issue by uninstalling opencv-python.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem. I install `opencv` and `PyQt` throungh pip and solve it.
So I advise that you can keep the way the same that opencv and `PyQt` are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using opencv with PyQt5 worked for me:

```
import os
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = '/path/to/qt/plugin'
```

To find the path/to/qt/plugin:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
    
# Initialize a QApplication instance to get access to system resources
app = QCoreApplication([])
    
# Get the path to the Qt plugins directory
qt_plugin_path = QCoreApplication.libraryPaths()[0]
print("Path to Qt plugins:", qt_plugin_path)
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer of @Mateen works great if you have Ubuntu version 17 and above. For Ubuntu 16, it's better to compile from sources your opencv python. As @Varun mentioned, follow the [opencv tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html). However, to successfully compile opencv with python 3 I have to add some flags in cmake command:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DPYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.5m/ -DPYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/ ..`

Hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS by uninstalling any OpenCV packages from `pip` and `apt` and installing OpenCV directly from source. Maybe this tutorial will help:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/15/how-to-install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but installation of matplotlib solved for me the problem with the error

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1d2c9cf0) is not the object's thread (0x1d347b20).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1d2c9cf0)
```

I emphasize that I prepared fresh conda environment where matplotlib was installed. Opencv was installed by pip in conda env as follow `pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python`.

Comment: You should install either `opencv-python` or `opencv-contrib-python`, not both, as per the official documentation of the second package.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the solution suggested by @Varun and it worked for me (using Python 3).
However, I didn't install the built files, as I do not have the admin rights on the system where I need the cv package. A `cmake`, followed by `make` was enough, I then took the `cv2.*.gnu` file from `../build/lib/python3` folder and replaced the one in the `site-packages/cv2` folder of my virtual environment

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Using opencv imshow function raised the moving thread error. Eventually, I found that Ubuntu 16.04 has a preinstalled pyqt5 while OpenCV needs pqty4.
Therefore, this may be caused by conflicting installations of Qt libraries. The following command fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove libqt5x11extras5 libqt5x11extras5-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

I know the thread is a bit old but posting for anyone else out there, I faced the same problem and it was because even after running

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

there was another version of open-cv in my system which I checked by

```
pip list
```

(I'm guessing that pip only removes the first version it finds)
So I ran this command again

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

And now simply installing opencv by

```
pip install opencv-python
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using **matplotlib**, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49887744/13268880

TL;DR: `matplotlib.use('Agg')`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32346921)

Answer (score -2):

This may be caused by conflicting installations of Qt libraries. The following command fixed it for me:

sudo apt-get remove libqt5x11extras5 libqt5x11extras5-dev

Comment: This deletes important system libraries and can make your system unusable. Don't run this unless you know exactly what it does.