# "'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create'" but if installed from pip the gui gives qt thread error

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, python-3.6

I'm trying to run a python script for a basic face recognition but when running after installing from pip I get the error:

`QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x24c8e90) is not the object's thread (0x20da6d0).
    Cannot move to target thread (0x24c8e90)`

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449850/how-to-fix-the-error-qobjectmovetothread-in-opencv-in-python) and it solved the problem but after that I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "face_recognition.py", line 21, in 
        recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create'`

I found many answers ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer#44641712)) to this problem but all suggested to install the `opencv-contrib-python` package from pip.
How can I include the needed package from apt-get?

The code where I get the error:

    `import cv2
    import numpy as np
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

Comment: That is a valid solution, why don’t you do pip? It’s also one liner as is apt-get.

Comment: @QuangHoang as I said, when I install from pip I get the Qobject error.

Comment: Then you should try installing opencv from source with CMake.

Comment: @QuangHoang I'll try thanks.