# Uninstalled opencv-python but still able to import cv2. How is this possible?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, pip

**Tl;dr** - after I had [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449850/how-to-fix-the-error-qobjectmovetothread-in-opencv-in-python) with clashed versions between `opencv` and `QT`, I uninstalled `opencv-python`. But somehow I am still able to import and use `cv2` inside python. How is that possible? What am I missing? Where is this `opencv-python` still installed?

Some more details:

1. My tech spec: Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6, PyCharm Community 2020.3.
2. My actions:

   uninstalled opencv: `pip3 uninstall opencv-python` (process was successful)

   validated it was indeed uninstalled: `pip3 freeze | grep opencv-python` (return nothing)

   validated also inside PyCharm that my environment does not have the package installed (I only work with my environment but just to make double-sure...)
3. To my surprise:

   Inside python, `import cv2` is a success, and I am able to use all functionality (well, at least the ones I tested...)

**=> My question: how is this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

After many frustrations, I found the answer - according to [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html), on Ubuntu the `opencv-python` installation is with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

Indeed I have `python-opencv` installed with `apt-get`.

The error I initially had, with the clash between the `opencv` and `QT` - was actually **caused** by my **additional** `pip` installation of `opencv`.

Conclusion - on Ubuntu, DO NOT use `pip install opencv-python`!

A question is remained to be asked why it is allowed to make this installation, but that's probably for another day...