# why can't I do any GUI on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, qt, pythonanywhere

While running the following shell command  (via  pyhtonanywhere bash):

```
cv2.imshow('Mask',mask)
```

I get the error message:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/teki/.virtualenvs/bup/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" ev
en though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

As suggested in this forum (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120450/error-2unspecified-error-the-function-is-not-implemented-rebuild-the-libra)) I unistall opencv-python and installed then opencv-python-headless, message raised the gollowing error message:

```
pythonanywhete cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1267: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. R ebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re -run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

Comments on this forum suggest to uninstall opencv-python-headless and to install opencv-python...which brings me back to my initial problem.

Any tip on this problem would be highly appreciated.

PS- in case it helps, here's the full script:

```
# import required libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input image
img = cv2.imread('car.jpg')

# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of blue color in HSV
lower_yellow = np.array([15,50,180])
upper_yellow = np.array([40,255,255])

# Create a mask. Threshold the HSV image to get only yellow colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)

# display the mask and masked image
cv2.imshow('Mask',mask) #my script runs well till this line. 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('Masked Image',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you install **OpenCV** *"headless"*, that means it doesn't have access to a screen to display graphical images so you can't use `cv2.imshow()` to display images and you'll have to use your system's image viewer or something else (e.g. **matplotlib**, `imgcat` or somesuch) to display it. If you install it normally, i.e. not headless, you need to have a screen/display available for `cv2.imshow()` to access - that likely means you need a properly configured X11 server that all X11 programs (such as `xclock`) can display on, or you need something that runs Qt or similar.

Comment: try installing pip3 install opencv-python==4.1.2.30

Comment: Thanks @Mark Setchell, not only you answered my needs, but also helped me to learn something new... I should close the topic, not sure though how to credit your comment as the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051790/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb)

Comment: pythonanywhere is a web site. code running on web servers can't show any GUI.

Comment: I'm kind of repeating what @ChristophRackwitz said, but to put it in different words: when you run code on PythonAnywhere, it's running on a server in a datacenter, not on your own computer.  That server does not have a display, so you can't run GUI code on it (and if it did have a display, you wouldn't have access to it).